# How do I loop adding the month to each date until the condition is met? google apps script

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, do-while

How do I loop adding the month to each date until the condition is met?

Explanation : I want to add 3 months to each date every time until the annual column (column D) will be greater than the today's date ( column E).

[image]

**Example :** If we took the first line of the column Annual " 01/02/2021" and we add at first 3 months the results will be 01/05/2021 then we add second time 3 months 01/08/2021 ..etc until it will be 01/05/2022 ( Greater than the today's date).

In the column "H" I've write the results I want, but whats I've got is in the column "F" by Red.

Here's my code :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  for (var i = 2; i < 12; i++) {
    var today_date = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    var today_date_format = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today_date), "Europe/Paris", 'MMMM dd, yyyy 12:00:00 Z');
    var Date_2021 = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    var Date_2021_Format = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Date_2021), "Europe/Paris", 'MMMM dd, yyyy 12:00:00 Z');
    var Date_2021_constructed = new Date(Date_2021_Format);
    var a3date = Date_2021_constructed.getMonth();
    Date_2021_constructed.setMonth((a3date + 3) % 12);
    do {
      Date_2021_constructed = Date_2021_constructed.setMonth((a3date + 3) % 12);
    } while (Date_2021_constructed > today_date_format);
    ss.getRange(i, 6).setValue(Date_2021_constructed)
  }
}
```

Here's the screen of my data :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPFFS.png)

Comment: [setMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) can handle values outside of the range 0, 11.  I suggest you remove your `% 12`s

Comment: Hi @James, thank you for your reply, I've tested but nothing happened ..

Comment: It would be helpful to have a screen shot of you spreadsheet with an explanation of what is going on inside of your spreadsheet within the scope of the current issue.  Giving us insight into what you are attempt to do may assist our understanding of what will help and what will hinder progress here.

Comment: Thank you so much @Cooper for your reply, I will add a screen and more explanation soon

Comment: @Cooper I"ve add the screen and edit my text with more explanation and example , Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the example and the image that helps a lot:

I'm going to suggest a quick fix and see if it works.  It looks like you may be posting the value of the date in millisecond in column f.  So try this:

`ss.getRange(i, 6).setValue(new Date(Date_2021_constructed)).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");`

If this doesn't work I'll take a closer look and it would be helpful to have a table of values from your spreadsheet so that I can test.

If the above solution does not work then try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,5).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let td = new Date(r[4]);
    let tdv = td.valueOf();
    let ad = new Date(r[3]);
    let m = r[2];
    let n = 1;
    do{
      var fd = new Date(ad.getFullYear(),ad.getMonth() + (n++ * m), ad.getDate());
      var fdv = fd.valueOf();
    }while(fdv<tdv);
    sh.getRange(i + 2,6).setValue(fd).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @cooper, very helpful, and I'm very glad to have learned new methodology and functions